# Replace single quote ( ' ) from each record in list JS

Tags: javascript, string, replace, quotes

so I have a list like this:

```
[
  '32350.0*51355000*9999',
  '6604.5*23680102*9999', 
  '14500.0*23680202*9999' 
]
```

And I want to look like this:

```
[
  32350*51355000*9999,
  6604*23680102*9999, 
  14500*23680202*9999 
]
```

My problem is, I try every way i know to replace the single quote but, nothing work, so far so god, I got this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < impuestos.length; i++) {
    formateo = impuestos[i]
    impuestos[i] = formateo.replaceAll(/'/g, "")
}

console.log(impuestos);
```

But I still getting the same result, any idea of how can i do it? Thank you very much to all!

Comment: You mean... you want to `eval` the result of `32350*51355000*9999`  into `16611681165750000
`?

Comment: No, i just want to replace the single quote from all the records in the list, that's all

Comment: But I think you have an array of strings right? There is no quote to replace in the records because there is no quote present.

Comment: That's tricky, because you can't replace something. The single quotes just represent/wrap your strings in the array and are not part of the string itself. If the strings were no strings, they couldn't stand like this in the array.
A list of integers would be the product of your multiplications, as @RokoC.Buljan implied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single quotes denote the `type` of data that you're representing... You're representing a `String` (a text element), so you get `''` around the elements in the console.

That's just the way it is.

If you were to render them, say on a webpage, they wouldn't have the quotes around them, if that's what's concerning you?

Comment: Ok, yes, that's was a little tricky, in my concern, i was thinking that's a quote from the str, but as you say, it isn't, now, i know how to work, thank U very much!